# Http Post - comunication failed - why?

Tags: java, database, http, post, http-post

I wrote a HTTP POST in Java (Android Studio) to get some information out of a NodeRed Database.

**When I execute this code, no errors accure. But the database creates an entry with empty fields and the response which should give a JsonArray with data is just an empty JsonArray.**

Does anybody see the mistake? If I test the database with Postman, everything works fine. More than that, I already coded a GET without any parameters and it works fine too.

This is my POST method:

```
URL url = new URL("https://example-page.de/ExistingUser");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
String boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary); 
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
con.setRequestProperty("Host", "example-page.de");
con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
con.setRequestProperty("Cache-control", "no-cache");
con.setUseCaches (false);
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);

//Create REQUEST content
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream ());
PrintWriter writer;
String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
String charset = "UTF-8";
String name = "EMail";
String value = "hans.wurst";
writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"").append(LINE_FEED);
writer.append("Content-Type: application/json; charset=" + charset).append(LINE_FEED);
writer.append(LINE_FEED);
writer.append(value);
writer.flush();
writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
writer.close();

//Read Response
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
content = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        content.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
con.disconnect();
```

[I only put in this Parameter in the body.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iFms.png)

Comment: Can you share what you are doing in Postman to say "everything works fine"?

Comment: You can find the link in the edit.

Comment: Can you output what you have put to `writer` using a regular `System.out`? Let's check that it really contains what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not added the form data part to the correct output stream.
You do not need to create another printwriter.

```
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream ());
//PrintWriter writer;
String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
String charset = "UTF-8";
String name = "EMail";
String value = "hans.wurst";
wr.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
wr.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"").append(LINE_FEED);
wr.append("Content-Type: application/json; charset=" + charset).append(LINE_FEED);
wr.append(LINE_FEED);
wr.append(value);
wr.flush();
wr.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
wr.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
wr.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

**First thanks for your help!**

I tried it, but it doesn't worked.
We have a Virtual Machine on the Server of our university. And our URL is passed through the default PORT inside the server to our virtual machine. Could this be the problem? So maybe the content of the body is not passed inside from the first webserver to our second one? Because if I use query parameters or create new key-value pairs inside the header, there is no problem. And everything works fine.

But now I have another problem. When I do the GET request with query params, I can use the normal URL. But when I try to do the POST with query params I need to use the local IP of the server and connect my phone to the local network of my university. This is very confusing, I can't see any reasons for that?
Do you have an idea?